# How can I reference the fields of an object in an array?

Tags: java

Is there an array that I can reference the fields of an object from?
The objects fields are of type `String`, `String`, `String` and `int`. Is it possible to reference these through an array?

Comment: start with a java tutorial on arrays http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare an array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java)

Comment: If the objects/values were put *into* an array manually (that is, there is no idiomatic way in Java to "enumerate properties" and reflection is likely not appropriate). However, given the inclusion of the `int` value I expect this is *not* what is actually desired (the best-fitting array would also be `Object[]` after wrapping the integer) - sequences, like arrays, work best with *homogeneous* data. Explaining the *actual* goal/problem and showing *actual* code will likely lead to more useful responses (as most of the answers don't seem to apply).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you have something like this?

```
public class SomeThing
{
    public String thing = "something";
    public String thing2 = "somethingElse";
    public String thing3 = "anotherThing";
    public int id = 42;
}
```

And you want to access those as an array?

If so, you can do this reflectively, like so:

```
SomeThing instance = new SomeThing();
Field[] fields = instance.getClass().getFields();
Object[] array = new Object[fields.length]
for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    fields[i].setAccessible(true);
    array[i] = fields[i].get(instance);
}
```

Comment: +1 because it appears to be the only answer written after actually reading the question and formulating a reasonable hypothesis from the request, as vague as it is.. however, at this level of understanding reflection is mostly likely not the "correct" approach to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference an object in an array with the `[]` operator. From there on, it's just a normal reference. E.g.:

```
myObjectArray[4].getSomePropertyOfMyObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Can you explain it better.
You can have an Array of objects in Java.

If for example your object is called **Animal** you can create an array of Animals like this:

```
Animal[] animals= new Animal[sizeOfAnimals];
```

Is it what you want? Just substitute Animal with your object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cat [] list = new Cat[10];
```

So once you have a list and objects of a type inside the list then you can call them like you would any other object.

```
 list[0].methodName();
```

Notice `list[0]` behaves like a Cat object, because that is what it holds.